# Code First ForeignKeyAttribute on property … on type … is not valid

Tags: c#-4.0, model-view-controller

This is my parent  class

```
public class Artist
{
    public int ArtistID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual  List<Album> Albums { get; set; }

    public virtual  ArtistDetails ArtistDetails {get;set;}

}
```

This is my child class..

```
public class ArtistDetails
{
    [Key()]
    [ForeignKey("Artist")]
    public int ArtistID { get; set; }

    public string bio { get; set; }

    public virtual  Artist artist { get; set; }
}
```

when I run my solution it shows following error...

The ForeignKeyAttribute on property `ArtistID` on type `EntityframeWorkDemo.Models.ArtistDetails` is not valid. The navigation property `Artist` was not found on the dependent type `EntityframeWorkDemo.Models.ArtistDetails`. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is the artist property in the ArtistDetails in lowercase ?

Comment: it's a name i can give it in caps or small

Comment: Seems like you're doing the MVA on Implementing Entity Framework with MVC (so am I, although I'm doing it in VB.NET). I got around this simply by removing the ForeignKey attribute.